# Why isn't behave's documented manual integration with Django working?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-behave

I have a Django (1.10.2) project ("theproject") and some behave (0.4.0) features. I've been using behave-django. `python manage.py behave` works. However, [PyCharm (which uses the `behave` executable rather than a Django management command) doesn't know how to run my features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208517/how-to-run-behave-django-features-in-pycharm), so I'm attempting to use [behave's documented "manual integration" with Django](http://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html).

My entire `features/environment.py`:

```
import os
import django
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner
from django.test.testcases import LiveServerTestCase
from splinter.browser import Browser

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "theproject.settings"

def before_all(context):
    django.setup()
    context.test_runner = DiscoverRunner()
    context.test_runner.setup_test_environment()
    context.old_db_config = context.test_runner.setup_databases()
    context.browser = Browser('phantomjs')

    # When we're running with PhantomJS we need to specify the window size.
    # This is a workaround for an issue where PhantomJS cannot find elements
    # by text - see: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/585
    if context.browser.driver_name == 'PhantomJS':
        context.browser.driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024)

def before_scenario(context, _):
    context.test_case = LiveServerTestCase
    context.test_case.setUpClass()

def after_scenario(context, _):
    context.test_case.tearDownClass()
    del context.test_case

def after_all(context):
    context.test_runner.teardown_databases(context.old_db_config)
    context.test_runner.teardown_test_environment()

    context.browser.quit()
    del context.browser
```

Here's `INSTALLED_APPS` from `theproject/setting.py` in case it's helpful (I removed `'behave-django'` for this experiment):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'push_notifications',
    'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
    'rest_framework',
    'app1.apps.App1Config',
    'app2',
    'django.contrib.admin'  # Must follow apps for apps' models to appear in admin UI
]
```

When I run `behave` I get

```
Exception AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/behave", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/__main__.py", line 109, in main
    failed = runner.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 672, in run
    return self.run_with_paths()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 678, in run_with_paths
    self.load_step_definitions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 658, in load_step_definitions
    exec_file(os.path.join(path, name), step_module_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 304, in exec_file
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "features/steps/common.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 105, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 237, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

**How can this way of integrating django and behave be made to work?**

Something I tried that didn't work (or not completely): I moved `django.setup()` to the top level of `environment.py`, right after setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. That fixes `AppRegistryNotReady`, but many scenarios fail with

```
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=(username) already exists.
```

Under behave-django a transaction was started before each scenario and rolled back afterwards; that seems not to be happening now. `LiveServerTestCase` extends `TransactionTestCase`, so I'm puzzled.

Comment: **AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.** This error erupts when the apps in INSTALLED_APPS settings are not in the right hierarchy. I suggest you check that. If the problem still persists then please share the INSTALLED_APPS settings.

Comment: Also, check answers of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276397/django-1-7-upgrade-error-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186413/djangodjango-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet

Comment: Thanks for the first suggestion, but my app runs, my django.test.TestCase  tests pass, and, when I use when I use behave-django, my behave features run, so it seems like INSTALLED_APPS must be OK. Correct?

Comment: Regarding those other questions: Most answers don't apply. The one suggesting `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model` didn't make any difference. I had already tried putting `django.setup()` at the top of `environment.py`; I'll add the unsuccessful result to my question.

Comment: Dave, can you tell us the Django version you are using? Python is obviously 2.7. I've asked Andrey to look at this SO question via his blog post (comments). He is the original author of the integration published as "Manual Integration" in the Behave docs.

Comment: I still think that the error is somewhere in the settings.py file, Mainly INSTALLED_APPS may be.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Try this answer also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537905/django-1-7-throws-django-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-models-arent-load

Comment: What `LiveServerTestCase` transaction management are you referring to?

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi I don't see any applicable answers in that other question. I added INSTALLED_APPS to the question.

Comment: I suspect that your database changes won't be rolled back between scenarios (hence the `IntegrityError`). The database is only torn down in `after_all()`. Try moving all code into the `before_scenario` and `after_scenario` functions, just for now to see if you can get things working. https://pythonhosted.org/behave/api.html#environment-file-functions
--
Also, you may try to use `StaticLiveServerTestCase `, which is what we use with `behave-django`, but that's surely unrelated to your current issues.

Comment: @knbk `django.test.LiveServerTestCase` extends `django.test.TransactionTestCase`, which starts a transaction in `setUpClass` and rolls it back `tearDownClass`. The `IntegrityError`s suggest that that's not happening.

Comment: Alright, this is something specific because I was able to run empty test feature the Python 2.7 with latest Django and the configuration above (phantom replaced by chrome). I can share my code somewhere.

Comment: Here we go https://git.anvileight.com/andrey.zarubin/behavetest

Comment: @Peterino moving `setup`/`teardown_databases` is sufficent to resolve the `IntegrityError`s. Doing `management.call_command('flush', verbosity=0, interactive=False)` also works and is faster. I'll probably need that level of database cleanup when I write features against async Javascript UIs (the features in this project happen to not touch any async Javascript), so that's likely to be my long term solution and you might want to write it up as an answer. It would still be good to know how to get transaction rollback to work.

Comment: @AndreyZarubin thanks for taking a look. You'd need to import `django.contrib.auth.models.User` in a step file and create a `User` in a step (`User.objects.create_user('username'`) to see the issues I'm having.

Comment: Have you tired what @Peterino suggest?

Comment: @AndreyZarubin yes (see my comment immediately before my previous response to you) and it works, although it doesn't use transactions (which would be faster) as the documented manual integration intends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database changes won't be rolled back between scenarios (hence the `IntegrityError`). The database is only torn down in `after_all()`. Try moving all code into the `before_scenario` and `after_scenario` functions (see [related docs](http://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#environment-file-functions)).

The execution time of your tests will increase, but the tests will be isolated. And as a quick fix this makes them pass for now at least. Hints for cleaner solutions in the comments and alternative answers.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have misunderstood what `TransactionTestCase` (and `LiveServerTestCase`) does with relation to transactions. It's not a test case that uses transactions to run your tests and roll back changes at the end (this is what Django's "regular" `TestCase` does). It's a test case that does *not* use transactions to you can test *your own* transactions:

> Django’s TestCase class is a more commonly used subclass of TransactionTestCase that makes use of database transaction facilities to speed up the process of resetting the database to a known state at the beginning of each test. A consequence of this, however, is that some database behaviors cannot be tested within a Django TestCase class. For instance, you cannot test that a block of code is executing within a transaction, as is required when using select_for_update(). In those cases, you should use TransactionTestCase.

([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase))

`TransactionTestCase` still resets the database by flushing all tables, firing the post-migrate signal and reinstalling fixtures, but it runs under the assumption that `__call__` is called on the test case. It seems that behave is [calling `run()` directly](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/behave/runner.py#L541), so it skips the setup/teardown of database data for each test.

You can probably fix this by creating your own subclass that calls `_pre_setup()` and `_post_teardown()` in `setUp()` and `tearDown()`. The only caveat is that every subclass that overrides `setUp()` or `tearDown()` *must* call `super()`, or `_pre_setup()`/`_post_teardown()` won't be called.

```
class BehaveLiveServerTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self._pre_setup()

    def tearDown(self):
        self._post_teardown()
```

Comment: It turns out that behave-django does call `__call__` on the test case, so I went with that.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the error is actually at

```
  File "features/steps/common.py", line 5, in <module>
```

Which tries to load the User before loading the apps. Try to move import inside `step_impl`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That would fix `AppRegistryNotReady` at that point, but it would be unpleasant to have to import models in every step. `django.setup()` at the top level is less invasive.

Comment: Well, it depends on your philosophy :) I personally would prefer to have it in each step but up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with. It allows my features to run under the `behave` command without behave-django, and thus to run in PyCharm run configurations, without changing the features or steps. `BehaviorDrivenTestCase` and calling `context.test()` in `before_scenario` are copied from behave-django internals. I'm omitting browser setup and teardown and some other bits not relevant to this question.

```
import os
import django
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from django.core import management
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "api.settings"
django.setup()

def before_all(context):
    context.test_runner = DiscoverRunner()
    context.test_runner.setup_test_environment()
    context.old_db_config = context.test_runner.setup_databases()

def before_scenario(context, _):
    context.test = BehaviorDrivenTestCase()
    context.test.setUpClass()
    context.test() # this starts a transaction

    context.base_url = context.test.live_server_url
    def get_url(to=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return context.base_url + (
            resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs) if to else '')
    context.get_url = get_url

class BehaviorDrivenTestCase(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    """
    Test case attached to the context during behave execution

    This test case prevents the regular tests from running.
    """

    def runTest(*args, **kwargs):
        pass

def after_scenario(context, _):
    context.test.tearDownClass()
    del context.test

def after_all(context):
    context.test_runner.teardown_databases(context.old_db_config)
    context.test_runner.teardown_test_environment()
```

Isolating scenarios in transactions won't work for scenarios that exercise a UI that uses async Javascript. Removing `context.test()` and adding `management.call_command('flush', verbosity=0, interactive=False)` at the beginning of `before_scenario` also works, takes about the same amount of time, and should work better with async Javascript.